# How to add click-to-add auto-fill cards in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I add a form where along with giving a custom text input, we can also add some pre-built choices on the screen. If we click on these choices the form gets auto-filled with this choice?

Further detailed explanation:

If we have a form in Bootstrap HTML. The user can fill it in with a text input. Apart from this if the user wishes they can just click on some pre-built options to fill the form with the contents of this option.

Comment: first of all you didn't provide any code what did you try.. secondly it's possible to add pre-build text inside input.. in 2 ways client side and server side.  so which way you prefer ?

Comment: Apart from the usual dropdown menu, I do not know any other option to try. I want it on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something like Google search suggestions then the [<datalist>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) tag has the ability to display suggestions for inputs. MDN defines it this way:

> The HTML  element contains a set of  elements that represent the permissible or recommended options available to choose from within other controls.

### Bootstrap datalist solution

In this case, without relying on the server, the options are pre-written as raw data.
Bootstrap does not have a clear template for datalists, but the `custom-select` class can be a good alternative.

```html
<!-- Libraries -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datalist implementation -->
<label for="web-browser-choice">Web browser choice:</label>
<input class="custom-select" list="suggested-browsers" id="web-browser-choice" name="web-browser-choice" />

<datalist id="suggested-browsers">
    <option value="Brave">
    <option value="Google Chrome">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Lynx">
    <option value="Microsoft Edge">
    <option value="Mozilla Firefox">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
    <option value="WorldWideWeb">
</datalist>
```